# PDO issue with displaying appropriate data

Tags: php, pdo

To begin with, I'm having this small PDO snippet of code which gets me all available databases on the server and another function for the tables:

I need whenever I select and submit an option from the db list to display its corresponding tables in the select menu below. I managed to display the databases with a foreach but I kinda miss the point why this doesn't work.

Thanks in advance for any answers/solutions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see below for a revision to your code in order to achieve what you're looking for.

```
<form method='post' action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<?php

define('PDO_USER', 'root');
define('PDO_PASS', '');

function getDatabases(PDO $pdo) {
    $stmt = $pdo->query('SHOW DATABASES');
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

    $dbs = array();
    foreach($result as $row) {
        $dbs[] = $row['Database'];
    }

    return $dbs;
}

$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost', PDO_USER, PDO_PASS);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$databases = getDatabases($pdo);


// Table code
$selectedDB = (!empty($_POST['database'])) ? $_POST['database'] : null;
function getTables(PDO $pdo, $databaseName) {
    if(!in_array($databaseName, getDatabases($pdo))) {
        return array();
    }

    $stmt = $pdo->query('SHOW TABLES FROM '.$databaseName);
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

    $tables = array();
    foreach($result as $row) {
        $tables[] = $row['Tables_in_'.$databaseName];
    }

    return $tables;
}

$tables = array();
if(!empty($selectedDB)) {
    $tables = getTables($pdo, $selectedDB);
}


?>
Database: 
<select name='database'>
    <?php foreach($databases as $row): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row; ?>"><?php echo $row; ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>&#160;
<input type='submit' name='formSubmit' value='Submit'></form>
UPDATE
<select name='formTable1'>
  <?php foreach($tables as $tbName): ?>
   <option value='<?php echo $tbName; ?>'><?php echo $tbName; ?></option>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

A couple of notes:

1. You need to include the "action" attribute in the form tag in order to give the form a target URL for submission.
2. In your original select you had 2 name attributes
       (name='formDatabases[]' name='database'). You should only have one
       name per form element, which is what is determined to be used as the
       key in the $_POST array for that particular field.
3. You should only use "name='var[]'" format in the HTML, if you expect
       that particular POST item to be an array in PHP. Otherwise you can
       just use "name='var'"
4. This may be out of the scope of your original question, but you may
       want to consider separating your database business logic into a separate
       class, to keep your HTML clean. For now at least, I updated the code to have
       the logic at the top of the file so that in can be extracted into a
       class more easily in the future. This avoids the perilous path into PHP Spaghetti string code!